# Derivative of Modified Bessel Function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, integration, greens-functions, propagator

I am working on an exercise in Quantum field theory (problem 2.3 in Peksin and Schroeder's *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*) and am using the solutions: (https://theoreticalmaximum.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/intro-to-qft-solutions2.pdf). On page six of the pdf it seems to suggest that $-\frac{d}{d\omega}K_0(\omega) = K_1(\omega)$. Whys is this true? How do I prove this? The pdf (on the same page) gives the defintion for $K_n$, but $n$ is said to be a half integer (1/2, 3/2, 5/2, etc) so I couldn't think of a way to use it for a proof. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I notice the PDF cites Wikipedia on modified Bessel functions. Which of [their facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) about $K_\alpha$, especially $K_1$, are you happy to see assumed in a proof that $K_0^\prime=-K_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how we define $K_\alpha$. For example, taking$$K_\alpha(\omega):=\int_0^\infty\cosh(\alpha u)\exp(-\omega\cosh u)du$$[gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)$$\frac{d}{d\omega}K_0(\omega)+K_1(\omega)=\cdots$$